# web app scalability and performance

Tags: performance, web-services, web-applications, scalability

can anyone suggest a good book which discusses performance considerations while building a highly scalable web application?
I am looking for a book that would help me

build a highly scalable web application
Help incorporate different strategies to improve the performance

Answer (score 0):

this sounds like what you're looking for- 
http://perftestingguide.codeplex.com/

see also: [Is there a good book on web application performance tuning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780601/is-there-a-good-book-on-web-application-performance-tuning)